# Copy Layers with groups and layers with data from one MXD to another

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, group-layer

Is there a way of copying one group of layers with data (`001_Group`) from one MXD(`group1.mxd`) to another(`group2.MXD`) with `arcpy`. As far as I understand all the layers in ArcMap are referenced as standalone layers in arcpy, so arcpy wouldn't know if for example `010_Subgroup` is beneath `001_Group`.

I have hundreds of large groups which have the same structure as `001_Group` but `layer_with_data` layers have different data sources. I already have a script to update all the layers within `001_Group` (in `group1.mxd`) with `002_Group` datasources and save as `group2.MXD`.

However, I want to keep all the groups within the same MXD, so `001_Group`, `002_Group` and so on are listed from top to bottom. There was one question posted how to move all layers with looping through with `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers`, but this does mess things up and layer structure is inverted or not in correct order, as you can see from the example TOC below that some layers need to be left empty or lots of subgroups.

Here is the code which produces `Group_002.mxd`, `Group_003.mxd` and `Group_004.mxd` separately, which I'm trying to make into a single MXD with Groups being organised from top to bottom:

```
import arcpy
########################################################################################################
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\temp\Proj\Group_001.mxd")
subGroupPath_010 = r"C:\temp\Proj\subGr_010"
subGroupPath_020 = r"C:\temp\Proj\subGr_020"
subSubGroupPath_021 = r"C:\temp\Proj\subGr_020\ssubGr_021"
subSubGroupPath_022 = r"C:\temp\Proj\subGr_020\ssubGr_022"

grp_noArr = range(2,5)
grp_nameArr = ["Group_002", "Group_003", "Group_004"]
########################################################################################################
for grp_no, grp_name in enumerate(grp_nameArr, grp_noArr[0]):
    fileName111 = str(grp_no) + "_" + grp_name
    srcOutName50d = str(grp_no) + "_" + grp_name

    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        if lyr.name == "001_Group":
            lyr.name = grp_name
        if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
            for lay_i in range(1,5):
                if lyr.name == "10" + str(lay_i) + "_layer_with_data":
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(subGroupPath_010, "RASTER_WORKSPACE", fileName111 + "_subgrp010_" + str(lay_i))

                elif lyr.name == "21" + str(lay_i) + "_layer_with_data":
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(subGroupPath_020, "RASTER_WORKSPACE", fileName111 + "_subgrp020_" + str(lay_i))
                elif lyr.name == "22" + str(lay_i) + "_layer_with_data":
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(subGroupPath_020, "RASTER_WORKSPACE", fileName111 + "_subgrp020_" + str(lay_i))
                elif lyr.name == "23" + str(lay_i) + "_layer_with_data":
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(subGroupPath_020, "RASTER_WORKSPACE", fileName111 + "_subgrp020_" + str(lay_i))

    mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\\temp\Proj\\" + grp_name + ".mxd")
```

[image]

Comment: What does your code for this bit so far look like?

Comment: Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can read the structure of the layers in the TOC. Work with the [`Layer`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) object.

> First, you can check to see if the layer supports the `isGroupLayer`
>   property. Second, you can evaluate the `longNameproperty`. A layer's
>   `longName` value will include the group name in addition to the layer
>   name. For example, a layer named `Layer1` in a group layer named `Group1`
>   will have a `longNamevalue` of `Group1\Layer1`. If the name value is equal
>   to `longName` value, then the layer is not a group layer or the layer is
>   not inside a group layer.

Using this properties, you will be able to work your way through all the layers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, great to see an option like `longName`, unfortunately it's `Read-only` according to documentation. This means I can query to see whether a `layer1` is within `Group1` with `longName`. However, what if I want to see `layer1`in `Group5\SubGroup2\` etc. How would I do that? I'm trying to understand how I can organize the hierarchy of TOC items in a way I want (or client wants).  I will try to post my code in a bit, as it was an example only. My script is actually too long to post.